# Finding time substrings from a string in java

Tags: java, search, timestamp, substring

I'm having huge log files, which contains events timestamps.
ex: 12/20/16 11:12:03 AM or 1/1/17 05:10:20 PM
Can anyone suggest me a good regex to finding these timestamp strings.

Comment: Have you tried looking for a regex tutorial?  You should be able to figure this one out easily, and then next time you need a regex for some other purpose you'll know how to do it yourself and you won't need to ask StackOverflow every time you need a regex.

Comment: @ajb I'm going through the tutorial, as i'm little newer to regex its taking time. Posted here for a quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between finding a possible timestamp and finding a definite, or valid, timestamp. The former is quite easy, the latter quite difficult. Here's a simple regex that will detect likely timestamps:

```
\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PV0rgw/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using following regex to find the timestamps. I find it's easy and can be modified to handle different formats.

```
"\\d+/\\d+/\\d+ \\d+:\\d+:\\d+ [A-Z][A-Z]"
```